# Is good to use static variable in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is good to use static variable in fragments? Because it is difficult to maintain the data between fragments while Poping and adding fragments or orientation change. savedInstanceState only help in orientation change not while poping back the previous fragments. P.S i'm going to save only arrays as static.

Comment: You can try an application class instead of static.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a base fragment class for all your fragment. and there is no problem to work with static variable.